# Spring multiple entity JSON serializers

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jackson, kotlin

I am looking for a way to create multiple json serializers for my entity. I have created service layer, custom serilizers and now I have problem with implementation of this things.
My Service class looks like:

```
@Service
class TeamsService(@Autowired private val teamsRepository: TeamsRepository) : ITeamsService{

override fun findAll(): String? {
    var objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    var simpleModule = SimpleModule()
    simpleModule.addSerializer(Teams::class.java, TeamsSerializer())
    objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule)
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(teamsRepository.findAll())
}
```

}

And my Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
class MainController(@Autowired private val teamsService: TeamsService) {

    @GetMapping("/teams")
    fun teams(): String? = teamsService.findAll()
}
```

Now I have problem that my response lost all headers and appears as text/plain not text/json, like it was before  I added custom mapper.
I Was reading about projections but I am not sure if I should use them. I do not want to have query parameters in my url.

Comment: What would you like to achieve with multiple serializers? Dynamic filtering?

Comment: Different json for different endpoints.

Comment: I want to have in response specific fields from my entities. On two endpoints i need diffrrent data to be return.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. The best way to do this is to use ModelMapper library. You can simply map entity to custom classes and serialize